# IllegalArguementException and BeanCreationException: No property found for type error

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-data

I have searched online and tried some suggested corrections but my app won't run . It throws no property for type exception as well as UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean.

When trying to run the code , it says Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to create query for method public abstract java.math.BigDecimal com.Wallet.Repository.TransactionRepository.getBalance(java.lang.Long)!No property getBalance found for type Transaction

This is the model code :

```
  @Entity
public class Transaction {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

    private BigDecimal amount;

    private java.util.Date transactionDate;

    private Long  transactionReference;

    private String details;

    @ManyToOne
    private UserWallet wallet;

    public Transaction() {
        super();
    }
```

**Repository**

```
@Repository
public interface TransactionRepository extends CrudRepository <Transaction, Long>

{
    Optional<Transaction> getTransactionByRef(Long reference)throws UserNotFoundException;

    BigDecimal balanceByUserAccountID(Long accountId);

    List<Transaction> transactionsByUserAccountID(Long Id)throws UserNotFoundException;

    Transaction createTransaction(Transaction transaction) throws LowBalanceException;

    BigDecimal getBalance(Long id);

}
```

**ServiceImpl**

```
    @Service
public class TransactionServiceImpl  {

   @Autowired
   private TransactionRepository transRepo;

   public Object transactionByRef(Long reference) throws UserNotFoundException {
       return transRepo.getTransactionByRef(reference).orElseThrow(
               () -> new UserNotFoundException(String.format("transaction with ref '%d' doesnt exist", reference)));
   }
   @Transactional
 public Transaction createTransaction(Transaction transaction) throws LowBalanceException {

       BigDecimal balance = transRepo.getBalance(transaction.getWallet().getId());

       if (balance.add(transaction.getAmount()).compareTo(BigDecimal.ZERO) >= 0) {
           return transRepo.save(transaction);
       }

       throw new LowBalanceException(String.format("user's balance is %.2f and cannot perform a transaction of %.2f ",
               balance.doubleValue(), transaction.getAmount().doubleValue()));
       }

 public BigDecimal balanceByUserAccountID(Long accountId) {

       return transRepo.getBalance(accountId);
   }
 public Iterable<Transaction> getList() {
       return transRepo.findAll();
     }
 public Optional<Transaction> transactionsByUserAccountID(Long txnRef) throws UserNotFoundException  {
       return transRepo.getTransactionByRef(txnRef);
   }
   public Iterable<Transaction> transactions() {
       return transRepo.findAll();
   }

}
```

**Controller**

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("v1/addMoney")
public class TransactionController {
@Autowired
private UserAccountServiceImp userRepo;

       @Autowired
       private TransactionServiceImpl transactRepo;

       @PostMapping("/{id}")
        public ResponseEntity addMoney(@PathVariable("id") Long userAccountId, @RequestBody TransactionDTO walletDTO) {

           Transaction saved;

           try {
                walletDTO.setUserAccountId(userAccountId);
                saved = transactRepo.createTransaction(TransactionMapper.dtoToDO(walletDTO));
            } catch (LowBalanceException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(UserController.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                return new ResponseEntity<String>(ex.getMessage(), HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(UserController.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                return new ResponseEntity<String>(ex.getMessage(), HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
            }
            return new ResponseEntity<TransactionDTO>(TransactionMapper.doToDTO(saved), HttpStatus.CREATED);

       }


       @GetMapping("v1/balance/{id}")
       public  BigDecimal getBalance(@PathVariable Long userAccountId){

             return transactRepo.balanceByUserAccountID(userAccountId);
          }
    }
```

Comment: what is the difference between `BigDecimal balanceByUserAccountID(Long accountId);` and `BigDecimal getBalance(Long id);`

Comment: problem has been fixed . It is the queries from the repository

Answer (score 0):

A Spring Data Repository does a lot of magic under the hood. If you have a method called `getBalance` defined in the repository interface, it expects that you're trying to get the value of column `balance` from the entity called `Transaction`.

Simply add a field called `balance` in your entity class and you should be good:

```
@Entity
public class Transaction {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

    private BigDecimal amount;

    private java.util.Date transactionDate;

    private Long  transactionReference;

    private String details;

    private BigDecimal balance;

    @ManyToOne
    private UserWallet wallet;

    public Transaction() {
        super();
    }
```